# How to check if X509Certificate is qualified electronic signature

Tags: java, security, x509certificate

I have an instance of `X509Certificate` in Java and I have to check if the certificate is qualified electronic signature. How to do it?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried using Digital Signature Service [link](https://github.com/esig/dss) to validate certificate and read data from reports (like this: [link](https://github.com/esig/dss/blob/master/dss-cookbook/src/test/java/eu/europa/esig/dss/cookbook/example/validate/CertificateValidationTest.java)), but I didn't find in reports information whether the certificate is qualified or not.

Comment: A qualified electronic signature is a political construction and therefore region specific. Are you referring to the qualified electronic signature in the European Union?

Comment: Yes ,I'm referring to qualified electronic signature in the European Union.

Comment: Electronic signature is qualified only when private key is saved on external cryptographic device. How to check this when I only have X509Certificate class instance?